# PHP/ajax table and Google results

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

A couple years ago I had a client with a limited budget and a short deadline who wanted a sortable searchable table of their parts inventory online - at the time they had only an excel spreadsheet. I created a database, then I just used Script Artist (because I had it) to do the front end. It all works great and he's been happy with it, except now we'd like to make sure that Google can actually find all 17,000+ parts they have available and not just the first 25.

The page where the inventory is located is just www.thesite.com/inventory.php and the url remains the same no matter what page you're on.

I've been looking around at different options, using pushState vs html snapshots, and I'm not sure what would be the best option or if I can even do anything with the current Script Artist setup or if I should just pitch the whole thing. I'd really rather not have to start over since he still doesn't have much of a budget, so if anyone could give me any input that would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what Script Artist is but you could use GET parameters so each page has its own URL.

Comment: As @chris85 said, you can add a GET parameter to the url: `http://www.your-url.com/your-list&page=1`

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I think I get it. The table has a select list for the user to change pages, I'd add (in jquery? ajax?) something to grab the value of the selected page and add it to the url. To be honest this is something altogether new to me so an example might be helpful.